# Motor control for multiple raspis

Tags: hat, cluster

I am building a Lego robotic arm with several motors. I plan to buy two [Build HATs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/build-hat.html) which can host up to 4 motors/sensors each. Since those HATs are not stackable, I presume I need to use 2 Raspis. The problem is that, since this is a single robot, I will most probably run my python code to control all 8 motors/sensors in a single file in one of the Raspis (let's call it master). What would be the best strategy to connect the 2 Raspis, so that I can run the script in one of them, but still be able to access the HAT in the other slave Raspi?